# Compare filed from object with item into list (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, compare, comparison, contains

Let say I got column names:

```
IList<string> selectedColumn = new List<string>{"Name", "City", "CreatedAt"};
```

Into loop from some entries I'm taking data:

```
foreach (Car car in rowsWithAllCar)
{
 string name = car.Name;
 string lastName = car.LastName;
 string city = car.City;
 string home = car.Home;     
 DateTime createdAt= (DateTime)car.CreatedAt;

 string[] allItems = {name, lastName, phone, city, createdAt}
}
```

How to check if for example value `car.LastName` or `car.Home` is not in `selectedColumn` ? As I don't want to add this to my `allItems`.

Result should be:

```
string[] allItems = {name, city, createdAt};
```

Comment: Your example will not produce any result at all, since it just declared a local `allItems` array that is only valid within the loop. This makes it quite difficult to understand what the actual intent is. If you just want to check if a list contains a value, there is `List.Contains`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolve it:

```
foreach (Car car in rowsWithAllCar)
{
IDictionary<string, string> carFields = new Dictionary<string ,string>();
 string name = car.Name;
 carFields.Add("Name", name);
 
 string lastName = car.LastName;
 carFields.Add("LastName", lastName);
 
 string city = car.City;
 carFields.Add("City", city);
 ...
 IList<string> allItems = new List<string>();

   foreach (var carField in carFields)
   {
       bool isInSelectedColumn = selectedColumn.Contains(carField.Key);
       
       if (isInSelectedColumn)
       {
         allItems.Add(carField.Value);
       }
   }
   //allItems.ToArray();     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
    List<string> compareString = new List<string>();

    compareString = selectedColumn.Except(allItems);
```